# No command 'intltool' found,

Tags: software-installation

Its installed. I've installed it via source and via apt get, and yet running it in the command line tells me it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed this same app. Indeed if you run intltool it says it doesn't show up. I think it's not one tool but a set of several. Type intltool in the terminal, but do not hit enter. Instead double hit TAB button. It should show you couple of different commands.Here's what i mean:

[image]

Side note: when I looked into the software-center before installing , it said intltool-debian was already installed.But those appear to be different files. It's one of the hidden packages:

[image]

Comment: yep. Unfortunately my problem extends beyond this, but you did answer the question properly so, thanks.

Comment: Well, let me know if I could help in other ways. I'm just learning so far, but always glad to give a problem at least a modest try